# Need to find $dy$ on $dx$ for $x^2+y^3-2y=3$

Tags: tangent-line

Need help - as I am not to sure how to do this Above.

I just need an example so that I can do it.

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+y^3-2y=3$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I tried turning the text into a formula. Please let me know if I did not get it right.

Comment: In situations where you can't find an explicit form for y(x), try implicit differentiation. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html

Comment: The formula is correct thanks - just need an example or a bit of help , as iam not too sure how to solve it

Comment: Oh and in the same sentence it also asks then find the slope of the tangent line at the point (2.1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Try implicit differentiation
2. Apply the chain rule,

i.e, $\frac d {dx}(y^3) = \frac d {dy}(y^3) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^3−2y=3$ --->(A)

By differentiating (A) with respect to x, we get

$2x + 3y^2 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - 2 \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

$or, \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2x}{3y^2 - 2}$

Slope of the tangent line at the point (2,1) = $\frac {dy}{dx}  at  (x,y)=(2,1) = \frac{-2*2}{3*1^2 - 2} = \frac{-4}{1} = -4$

[image]